# Onclick change image

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas

```
<div class="thumbimg">
    <ul class="list-unstyled">
       <li class="timgare"><img src="images/F.png" class="dummy_data" id="vader"></li>
       <li class="timgare"><img src="images/L.png" class="dummy_data" id="c3po"></li>
       <li class="timgare"><img src="images/R.png" class="dummy_data" id="annakin"></li>
       <li class="timgare"><img src="images/B.png" class="dummy_data" id="bhdhs"></li>
    </ul> 
</div>
 <canvas id="c" style="border:1px solid black;"></canvas>
```

Here is my code. How will I change image by using onclick. I'm using the big thumbnail image as a canvas. I'm new in canvas so let me know how will I do that work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change image in element Onclick](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37006576/change-image-in-element-onclick)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check below working snippet.

```js
$(".timgare").on("click",function(){
  var imgsrc = ($(this).find("img"));
  draw(imgsrc);
  return false;
});
function draw(image){
  var canvas = $('#c')[0];
  canvas.width = 800;
  canvas.height = 800;
  var c = canvas.getContext("2d");
  var img = new Image();
  img.src = image.attr("src");
  img.onload = function(){
    c.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="thumbimg">
  <ul class="list-unstyled">
    <li class="timgare"><img width="100" src="http://www.planwallpaper.com/static/images/desktop-year-of-the-tiger-images-wallpaper.jpg" class="dummy_data" id="vader"></li>
    <li class="timgare"><img width="100" src="http://www.1zoom.net/big2/61/263820-Sepik.jpg" class="dummy_data" id="annakin"></li>
  </ul> 
</div>
<canvas id="c" style="border:1px solid black;"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Image to use:</p>

<img id="scream" width="220" height="277"
src="pic_the_scream.jpg" alt="The Scream">

<p>Canvas:</p>

<canvas id="myCanvas" width="240" height="297"
style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;">
Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag.
</canvas>

<script>
window.onload = function() {
    var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    var img = document.getElementById("scream");
   ctx.drawImage(img, 10, 10);
};
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

[Working Demo](http://www.w3schools.com/graphics/tryit.asp?filename=trycanvas_image)

Comment: That was not the exact example which I want to know

Comment: I want to change small images by using onclick but I'm using canvas that was not know well. Like a product details page product bid thumbnail as well as four small images. When I click on the small images it was change. That I want.